# Can a --secret value be provided to docker build directly on the command line?

Tags: docker, gitlab

This is the "typical" method of specifying a secret

`docker build --no-cache --progress=plain --secret id=mysecret,src=mysecret.txt .`

but is there a way to do something like

`docker build --no-cache --progress=plain --secret id=mysecret,value=$GITLAB_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE .`

Comment: That would be a *really* bad idea. Command lines are public; anyone on the machine, even completely untrusted accounts like `nobody` used to run code that hasn't been fully authenticated, could steal it.

Comment: One thing you might try (which would work if-and-only-if Docker reads the FD only one, front-to-back, without rewinding, and not from any subprocess that doesn't inherit its variables) would be `--secret id=mysecret,src=<(printf '%s\n' "$GITLAB_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE")`. If it works, that would be considerably more secure. (Note that it'll only work with `bash`, not `sh`, as the active shell).

Comment: (Environment variables *used* to be just as public, but we're talking decades-ago that that stopped being common practice, and Linux &c. locked them down to same-user-only).

Comment: see vault, it is a better way to deal with secrets https://hub.docker.com/_/vault/